# How to find the best combination of parameters from a very large sets?

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I have a processing logic which has **11 parameters**(let's say from parameter ***A*** to parameter ***K***) and different combinations of theses parameters can results in different outcomes.

```
Processing Logic Example:

if x > A:
    x = B
else:
    x = C

y = math.sin(2x*x+1.1416)-D

# other logic involving parameter E,F,G,H,I,J,K

return outcome
```

Here are some examples of the possible values of the parameters(others are similar, discrete):

```
A ∈ [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, ..., 0.2]
E ∈ [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 200]
```

**I would like to** find the combination of these parameters that results in the best outcome.

However, **the problem I am facing** is that there are in total
10^19 possible combinations while each combination takes 700ms processing time per CPU core. Obviously, the time to process the whole combinations is unacceptable even I have a large computing cluster.

Could anyone give some advice on **what is the correct methodology** to handle this problem?

---

Here is some of my thoughts:

**Step 1**. Minimize the step interval of each parameter that reduces the total processing time to an acceptable scope, for example:

```
A ∈ [0.01, 0.05, 0.09, ..., 0.2]
E ∈ [1, 5, 10, 15, ..., 200]
```

**Step 2**. Starting from the best combination resulted from *step 1*, doing a more meticulous research around that combination to find the best combination

But I am afraid that the best combination might hide somewhere that *step 1* is not able to perceive, so *step 2* is in vain

Comment: How are you defining "the best outcome"? Depending on that, it may be that mixed-integer nonlinear programming might be a relevant topic for you to look into

Comment: Can these parameters be represented as a set of simultaneous equations? If so, set them up as $11\times11$ and $1\times11$ matrices and use Cramer's Rule (determinants) to solve them.